# Provide full specifications of the given IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit

[image]

I have searched a lot in the internet about this IC, but I didn't get any answers. The markings are:

```
9903AJ
DM74LS94N
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DM74LS94N is obviously some variant of the famous 7400 series logic ICs.

Therefore I'd google for

- "74LS94 data sheet"
- "74LS94N data sheet"
- "7494 data sheet"

and see what turns up.

I'd also identify the makers logo and, if possible, pick that makers data sheet if multiple hits are returned.

---

n.b. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits) says 7494 is *"4-bit shift register, dual asynchronous presets"* so I'd hope a 74LS94 would be the low-schottky (LS) version of that.

Comment: i think the logo is similar to national semiconductor logo

Comment: @BASIL: Yes [DM prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400_series#Part_numbering_scheme) also means NatSemi.

Comment: yes it is national semiconductor product. Texas instruments acquired them. In their site also no details about this product

Comment: @BASIL: Extending my Google search approach leads to http://www.ti.com/product/sn7494

Answer (score 1):

The first two letters are the manufacturer code, but here is a TI datasheet that will show the logic function:

[TI SN7494 Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7494.pdf)

The LS in the middle is for "low power schottky" so you can check a family guide to see the electrical and switching characteristics of that family.